# Is it possible to search another storeview product name if current language store view is no result?

Tags: magento2, search, catalogsearch

My website have two store view which are in different language.
I use keyword "Clothes" to search in dutch store. It should be no result in magento since there are no product name in dutch contain "Clothes". Is it possible to search another language store view if current language store view do not have result ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. But you will have to add extra functionality. Have a look at the `\Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface` interface there is a method called `get` and `getById` there is a parameter `$storeId`, where you can use as a fall back if the current store doesn't not have the product you're looking for.

You will however have to extend the functionality of what ever search engine you're using.